# Python: create a new variable with the values of 2 separate lists

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I am running probes on a number of campus devices daily and log the Probe for each day to a file that takes the name: HOST-YYMMDD.txt (e.g. "Host1-Loc1-171219.txt")

I am trying to automate the generation of variables that would allow xlsxwriter to 'read' the correct files for the loops that I need to run afterwards.

```
H1L1 = "Host1-Loc1"
H1L2 = "Host2-Loc2"

Dates = [171219,171220,171221]
Hosts = [H1L1,H1L2]
```

I am trying to create variables using the name pattern "Probe[Date]" (e.g. "Probe171219", "Probe171220" etc.) that are equal to (respectively) the log files "Host1-Loc1-171219.txt" and "Host1-Loc1-171220.txt"

I have been able to print the value that I need to get for the Probe variables, but I've not managed to assign it to an actual variable in an automatic way.

```
for item in Dates:
   print('FileLocation',Hosts[0],'-',item,'.txt',sep='')
```

This prints:

```
FileLocation/Host1-Loc1-191219.txt
FileLocation/Host1-Loc1-191220.txt
```

The question is how do I assign this to variables that would be called "Probe171219" and "Probe171220", thus giving the result:

```
Probe171219 = FileLocation/Host1-Loc1-191219.txt
Probe171220 = FileLocation/Host1-Loc1-191220.txt
```

This far I've been populating my variables manually, but with over 50 new logs per day, it is not very salable.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary?

Comment: I did as per Rakesh'es example below (I am new to Python and did not know how about dictionaries). It works but defines variables with names such as 'Probe171219]' which makes them unusable further on due to the ']' in the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pault mentioned you can use a dictionary:

**Sample**:

```
Dates = [171219,171220,171221]
Hosts = ["H1L1","H1L2"]
d = {}
for i in zip(Dates,Hosts):
    d["Probe{0}".format(i[0])] = "FileLocation/{0}.txt".format(i[1])

print d
```

Result:

```
{'Probe171219': 'FileLocation/H1L1.txt', 'Probe171220': 'FileLocation/H1L2.txt'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the pieces of advice, Rakesh! The end result however gives me variables with a "]" in their name (e.g. 'Proble171219':'FileLocation/H1L1-171219.txt' that makes them impossible to manipulate further: e.g. if I do "open (Probe171219) as P1219:" Python comes back with the information that such variable is not defined. The variable "Probe171219]" cannot be open because of the "]" in the variable name. I am not certain how to go about this issue with the naming.

Comment: I dnt understand where are you getting "]"?

Comment: The "]" appears in the variable names that Python prints out. When I do a print(d) the output is: RESTART: <FilePath>/Scout.py 
{'Probe171219]': 'FileLocation/H1L1-171219.txt', ... }". So basically it appears in the dictionary entry that I wish to use as a variable for later manipulation. I managed to overcome the problem all together by auto-populating the log names in a list though. I did Host_Probes = [] /n LogDoc = 'FileLocation' /n/ for root, dirs, files in oswalk (LogDoc): /n for name in files: /n if H1L1 in name: /n Host_Probes.append(str((os.path.join(name[:18])))) and it works now.